# Set-PnPSite -LogoFilePath throws error? Which version of SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline required? Mine is 3.20.2004.0

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Which version of SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline does support below command? Mine is 3.20.2004.0 and trying to update Modern teamsite in sharepoint online environment.

Set-PnPSite -LogoFilePath c:\images\mylogo.png

Set-Variable : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LogoFilePath'.
At line:1 char:13
+ set pnpsite -LogoFilePath C:\Project\Images\FPASiteLogo.png
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Variable], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand

Comment: PLEASE, wrap your code in code formatting ... and do the same with your error messages. right now, your posted info is needlessly difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the same version PnP PowerShell which is the latest version and LogoFilePath parameter is available, please see the PowerShell snippet:

[image]

But the site needs to be a Moder Site:

[image]

[image]

Reference:

[Set-PnPSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Yes site Modern teamsite SharePoint online site. Did use the same command but same error. Thanks

Comment: How about uninstall and then reinstall the PnP PowerShell package ? this command is working in my side. And the parameter should be existed in this command.

Comment: I had multiple version installed. Removed all the versions "uninstall-module -Name SharePointPnpPowershellOnline -AllVersions" and then reinstalled it using -Force. Now the Set logo command does not throw error but it doesn't update the logo either. So not sure what can be done? I am manually able to change the logo but want to do it through PNP command

Comment: Directly download and install from here: 

https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/releases

Then try again to see if it works.